# using ordinary methods in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, methods, matlab-class

I am a little bit rusty on Oop. I have following code.

```
classdef diag2by2
    properties
        a;
        b;
    end
    methods
        function obj = diag2by2(a, b)
            obj.a = a;
            obj.b = b;
        end
        function obj = plus(obj1, obj2)
            temp = [obj1.a,  0; 0 obj1.b]+ [obj2.a, 0; 0 obj2.b];
            obj.a = temp(1,1);
            obj.b = temp(2,2);
        end
        function obj = minus(obj1, obj2)
            temp = -1*obj2;
            obj = plus(obj1, temp);
        end
        function obj = mtimes(obj1, obj2)
            temp1 = [obj1.a,  0; 0 obj1.b];
            temp2 = [obj2.a, 0; 0 obj2.b];
            temp3 = temp1*temp2;
            obj.a = temp3(1,1);
            obj.b = temp3(2,2);
        end
        function r = matrix(obj)
            r = [obj.a,  0; 0 obj.b];

        end
    end
end
```

I am trying to create a class for 2by2 diagonal matrix. I am having trouble with defining a method. I have, a method

```
    function r = matrix(obj)
```

This should convert my object to a diagonal matrix. But I get error when I try to use this method

> > a = diag2by2(1,2)

a =

diag2by2 with properties:

```
a: 1
b: 2
```

> > a.matrix()
> >     No appropriate method, property, or field matrix for class
> >     diag2by2.

Can someone help me with this?

Edit: whole class posted

Comment: Can you post the whole class?

Comment: I have posted the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `matrix` nested inside `mtimes`:

```
function obj = mtimes(obj1, obj2)
    temp1 = [obj1.a,  0; 0 obj1.b];
    temp2 = [obj2.a, 0; 0 obj2.b];
    temp3 = temp1*temp2;
    obj.a = temp3(1,1);
    obj.b = temp3(2,2);
function r = matrix(obj)
    r = [obj.a,  0; 0 obj.b];
end
end
```

**EDIT**: Did you just fix it?  Your post no longer looks like the above.

Comment: it was a problem in copying, i still have the problem

Comment: Weird:
`>> a.matrix`
`ans =`
     `1     0`
     `0     2`
Your code worked for me once I fixed that.